# Why ListView.getCount() is greater by 1 than Cursor.getCount()

Tags: android, listview

I have this code:

```
cursor = tbDispositivos.fetchAll();
if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
    TextView emptyText = (TextView) findViewById(android.R.id.empty);
    emptyText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
adapter = new DispositivosCursorAdapter(this, cursor);  

dispositivosList = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);  
dispositivosList.setAdapter(adapter);  

cursorCount = cursor.getCount();
listViewCount = dispositivosList.getCount();
```

`listViewCount` is greater by 1 than `cursorCount`. Why?

Comment: Show a screenshot of your logcat where you have printed the both counts , that means your cursorCount , listViewCount. They should not be different. Try printing all the values from listview row and cursor , then you should understand the mistake.

Comment: Did you override the `getCount()` method for your custom adapter? If so, show it as well.

Comment: headerViews and FooterViews also are part of the listview count. So do you have these in your listview?

Comment: getCount() methods states that it returns the number of items owned by the Adapter associated with this AdapterView. (This is the number of data items, which may be larger than the number of visible views.). Make sure you override ur custom adapter to return the cursor count.

Comment: @nandeesh - OK. I have a headerView !!

Answer (score 2):

```
cursor.getCount() // number of data items in the cursor
adapter.getCount() // number of data items passed in by the cursor (or at least that is what a custom adapter should report)
listview.getCount() // number of data items from the adapter + a header and/or footer view
```

So using a header or a footer will make the listview.getCount() greater by 1 than cursor.getCount(). If you use both a header and a footer then it will be greater by 2.